# JavaScript animation

Tags: javascript, animation

I am trying to animate a `div` moving `200px` horizontally in JavaScript.

The code below makes it jump the pixels, but is there a way to make it look animated without using jQuery?

```js
function () {
    var div = document.getElementById('challengeOneImageJavascript');
    div.style.left = "200px";
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: @Huangism he ask how to do it without jquery.

Comment: He said "without jQuery"

Comment: oh yea just saw that, why did he tag jquery into it!

Comment: I am going with *without jQuery* and removed the tag to avoid confusion

Comment: You have a CSS3 Compatible solution and a much wider approach with the interval that should work with all the modern browser(ie6+)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here is a basic animation setup:

```
function animate(elem,style,unit,from,to,time) {
    if( !elem) return;
    var start = new Date().getTime(),
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            var step = Math.min(1,(new Date().getTime()-start)/time);
            elem.style[style] = (from+step*(to-from))+unit;
            if( step == 1) clearInterval(timer);
        },25);
    elem.style[style] = from+unit;
}
```

To use:

```
animate(
    document.getElementById('challengeOneImageJavascript'),
    "left","px",0,200,1000
);
```

This example will animate the given element to slide linearly from 0px to 200px over a time of 1 second (1000 ms).

Comment: very thorough implementation with lots of features... like it

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as Accepted by clicking the big check mark right underneath the vote score ;)

Comment: This works great, thank you! How would you implement easing into it?

Comment: Well, this all was written before I discovered CSS3 transitions. At this point in time I highly recommend you use transitions over manually animating, as this gives you an [unlimited range of functions](http://cubic-bezier.com/) to animate with. With this, you'd just need JavaScript to do `document.getElementById('...').style.left = '200px';` and it will animate automatically.

Comment: That said, if you would like to maintain support in IE9 and below, you should continue to use this function. You can run `step` through some mathematical function with the following requirements: The function should be continuous in the range 0-1, and pass through (0,0) and (1,1). Start with just `Math.pow(step,2)` and go from there.

Comment: This is a great solution for a project that requires no CSS stylesheet.  I'm curious, was there any reason you chose 25 ms as your delay time?

Comment: @ayjay 25ms yields 50fps, which is usually pretty good. You're free to adjust this as desired, but ideally `requestAnimationFrame` should be used now instead of timers.

Comment: Please add fiddle too in the answer.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol after removing last line `elem.style[style] = from+unit;` it still works.. is that line really needed?

Comment: @neoDev That line serves as the first "frame" of animation, since the interval doesn't run at that point. If the element is already in the correct position for the first frame, it will have no visible effect.

Comment: Is there an easier way to do this for transform: rotate(xdeg)?

Answer (score 10):

You can easily do this through [CSS3-Transition](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp) :

```
#challengeOneImageJavascript {
    -webkit-transition: left .2s;
       -moz-transition: left .2s;
         -o-transition: left .2s;
            transition: left .2s;
}
```

Though, it is not supported by IE9 and earlier browser versions.

Comment: In a browser that supports such CSS that is

Comment: Please specify that this is css3 only

Comment: yeah - this answer, despite being voted for a lot, is one for the future, and is only supported by the latest browsers

Comment: It will just instantly move in non supported browsers. Since those browsers are really slow, maybe toning down the animations in them isn't so bad.

Comment: CSS `transition` is smooth for me, Javascript `setInterval` (no matter how small) always gave a choppy result.

Answer (score 2):

I did a ton of research, and I finally learned how to do it really well.

I like to place my program in a window.onload function, that way it dosn't run the code until the page has finished loading.

To do the animation, make a function(I'll call it the draw function) and call it what ever you want except reserved words, then at the very end of the draw function call the requestAnimationFrame function and give it the name of the function to be called next frame.

Before the requestAnimationFrame function can be used it must be declared.

See the code below:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  function draw() { //  declare animation function
    context.fillStyle = "white";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
    requestAnimationFrame(draw); // make another frame
  }
  var requestAnimationFrame = // declare the 
    window.requestAnimationFrame || // requestAnimationFrame
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || // function
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
  draw(); // call draw function
}
```

**Note:** Nothing after the line that calls the draw function will run, so you need to put everything you want to run before the line that calls the draw function.

Answer (score 1):

With JavaScript, you will have to use `setInterval` function or this is how it can be done in jQuery:

```
$('#challengeOneImageJavascript').animate({left: '=-5'});
```

Adust value (`5`) as per your needs as well as direction via `=-` or `=+`

**With Vanilla JavaScript:**

```
var interval;
var animate = function(id, direction, value, end, speed){
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    interval = setInterval(function() {
       if (+(div.style) === end) {
          clearInterval(interval);
          return false;
       }
       div.style[direction] += value; // or -= as per your needs
    }, speed);
}
```

And you can use it like:

```
animate('challengeOneImageJavascript', 'left', 5, 500, 200);
```

To stop animation any time, you would do:

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

**Note:** *This just a very quick way to do it to give you an idea.*

Comment: I'm afraid OP wants a javascript non Jquery solution.

Comment: The CSS version wouldn't work with all the IE, while this should work with pretty much all browsers. GJ

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use a javascript timeout function, and change the css value a little at a time. The easiest way would be to increment by a set amount each time until a threshold is reached, which would give you a linear animation, which would look clunky and amateurish compared to jQuery's default `swing` animation which follows a bezier curve approximately like an s-curve.

Untested code should do the linear animation

```
var lefty = 0;
var animate = function(){
    lefty += 20;
    var div = document.getElementById('challengeOneImageJavascript');
    div.style.left = lefty +"px";
    if(lefty < 200)
      setTimeout(animate(),100);
}

animate()
```

n.b. there are lots of improvements to make to that block of code, but it should get you going...

Comment: I got it to work with JQuery(which is a better option obviously) but Im trying to learn Javascript and the best way I know how is to try and get things working the hard way first

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way via css.

https://jsfiddle.net/pablodarde/5hc6x3r4/

translate3d uses hardware acceleration running on GPU.
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css

**HTML**

```
<div class="movingBox"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.movingBox {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #999;
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.moving {
  transform: translate3d(200px,0,0);
  background: #f00;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
const box = document.getElementsByClassName('movingBox')[0];

setTimeout(() => {
    box.className += ' moving';
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

[CustomAnimation](https://github.com/SamantaChinmoy/CustomAnimation) is a small libary for animating html elements which is written in pure js.You can use this libary.

Comment: Please explain more.

Comment: You can check the samples which are provided in [CustomAnimation](https://github.com/SamantaChinmoy/CustomAnimation) repo.
For example to animate one element, you have to call animate method in following pattern.  
animate(elementObj,styleObj,duration);

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.