# Add transition to images on my website

Tags: javascript, css

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var aImages = [ 
        "images/gaming/GTAV/GTAVReviewImage1.jpg",  
        "images/gaming/GTAV/GTAVReviewImage2.jpg",
        "images/gaming/GTAV/GTAVReviewImage3.jpg",
        "images/gaming/GTAV/GTAVReviewImage4.jpg",
        "images/gaming/GTAV/GTAVReviewImage5.jpg",
        "images/gaming/GTAV/GTAVReviewImage6.jpg",
        "images/gaming/GTAV/GTAVReviewImage7.jpg"];
    var oImage   =  null;  
    var iIdx     =  0;  
    function play() {
        try {
        if (oImage===null) { oImage=window.document.getElementById("review-images"); }
        oImage.src  =  aImages[(++iIdx)%(aImages.length)];  
        setTimeout('play()',5000);  
        } catch(oEx) {
    }
}
</script>
```

which changes the image on this page: http://chrisbrighton.co.uk/GTAV.php every five seconds.

How can I add image transition to it?

UPDATE: When I add `-webkit-transition` to the `img` tag nothing happens.

Thanks.

Comment: In JavaScript or CSS?

Comment: Please Google first before asking on SO. Searching "image transition css" should give plenty examples.

Comment: @putvande Either. I just want it too work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213259/javascript-animation)

Comment: When you added -webkit-transition to the image, you did this in CSS?  And what browser did you test with?

Comment: @Charlie74 I did, yes. I've used it before but I'm guessing it doesn't work because I have this piece of JavaScript code. I tested it in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do it. A lot of people have went to CSS3 now that there is some really cool animating and transition effects... You can control your ccs3 effects using javascript. For a detailed tutorial check [- controlling animations with javascript](http://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/)

Comment: Flagged - duplicate question