# count quickly from one number to another in a non linear way

Tags: javascript, count, nonlinear-functions

I have a number (float) lets say 4.37.
at some point this number is changed to another value that can be basically anthing, but still float and with 2 commas. What i need is a nice transition from the first number to the second one. In particular i am searching for way to display this like this:

from number A it starts growing quickly, and as soon as it gets near the second one it slows down. It should go from number A to B in about 0.8 seconds.

This number is displayed in a DIV.

Comment: I can't give you the exact code, but you can do this using the jQuery's animate functions and a custom update callback.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213259/javascript-animation) - specifically, see my answer there and you should be able to adjust it to work with plain numbers.

Comment: I think sharkyenergy just want to display one number increments or decrements to another number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `jQuery.Animation` for this, and use any easing or animate just about any property

```
var o = {value : $('#inp1').val};
$.Animation( o, {
    value: $('#inp2').val()
  }, { 
    duration: 800,
    easing : 'easeOutCubic'
  }).progress(function(e) {
      $('#result').text((e.tweens[0].now).toFixed(2));
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/947Bf/1/)

Answer (score 2):

There are really two questions here

1) what numbers do I pick as I run from one to another in 0.8 seconds

2) how do I make the updates appear

Now since they eye can't see more than about 20 frames per second (which is why film is 24 fps, and video usually even more), you want about 20 numbers in the transition (0.8 x 24).

Generating these numbers I would recommend you do:

```
var N=20;
for (i = 0; i < 20 ; i++) {
  f = (i/(N-1));
  num = low + (high - low) * Math.pow(f, 1/g);
}
```

As `g` gets bigger, the number will "slow down" more as it gets to higher values of `i`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using *sine* for the curve

```
function genFactory(a, b, n) { // n is number of steps
    var dif = b - a,
        pi2 = Math.PI / 2, // sin(Pi/2) === 1
        i = 0;
    return function () {
        if (i === n) return b; // short circuit at the end
        return a + dif * Math.sin(pi2 * ++i / n);
    };
}

// putting it to use
var a = 4.37, // start point
    b = 9.12; // example
// generate function
var f = genFactory(a, b, 100); // 100 steps
// "loop"
var i = window.setInterval( // consider a setTimeout in production code
    function () {
        var x = f();
        if (x === b) window.clearInterval(i);
        console.log(x.toFixed(2)); // whatever output
    },
    800 / 100 // 0.8 seconds over 100 steps
);
```